# Acrobat XI Pro not responding issue

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat

**System Spec**

- Windows 7 Professional x64 (all updates installed)
- Acrobat XI Pro including updates
- Sata III HDD
- i7 3770K CPU
- nVidia GTX 470
- Asus P6X58D-E : [link to asus page](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P6X58DE/)
- 24GB of RAM
- Corsair PSU 
  These are from memory and I have been known to be wrong but will amend when I get to my friends.

Hi all, I have browsed a few posts that I thought were related to this issue but couldn't quite find the right answers. I have a friend and this is his issue.

I open Acrobat XI Pro from the Desktop icon and it opens very quickly, like one second boom and its open.

If I open Acrobat XI Pro by clicking on a PDF file again it opens pretty fast, if I start to scroll the document by left click and move the cursor up and down using the scroll bar, Acrobat will stop responding and stay that way for approx 5-15 sec after which you can scroll like a crazy man all day long with no lag.

Any document after that will open fine an scrolling is not an issue.

Have tried clean booting, via msconfig etc, but nothing changed it, updated the bios to the latest one 0803, changed the SATA to ACHI from IDE. altered some settings in Acrobat as per some other posts, again can list a few more details when I get to my friends.

Comment: These local files or network files?

Comment: They are local files. I've tried a few more setting changes in Edit >  Preferences: Changed from DX9 to software and closed Acrobat, if I open the same file I opened prior to the change it will open Ok and not show "not responding" upon scrolling. If I open a different file after the change its locks up for approx 5 -15 sec